# Good Practice to pass arguments in queued connection

Tags: qt

I want an simple and clear example of how to do the signal and slot mechanism in queued connection.
Take the below line as example. Think that obj1 is backend functionality object emitting signal asynchronously from another thread and is connected to a slot in GUI ( main thread):

```
connect(obj1, SIGNAL(Mysignal(vector<mystruct> )), this, slot(myslot(vector <mystruct>)))
```

I have read that you have to register the types(meta types).
Please give a clear, simple and ready to use code lines for the above example that I would need, so that errors during run time like vector, my struct or string not defined, etc.. I don't face.

Also, is there a better way to handle this like sending pointers like:

```
connect(obj1, SIGNAL(Mysignal(obj2 *)), this, slot(myslot(obj2 *)))
```

Obj2 contains the vector of mystruct. Will i still need to register the obj2 with those metatypes?

If somebody has experience in this, please share all your good practices and simple code snippets, I am new to the queued connections with arguments. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a queued connection, you need to call connect with a 5. parameter `Qt::QueuedConnection`. Otherwise, you get a direct connection inside the thread where you sent the signal from. **Edit:** See Tobys comment below.

You must wrap a QVector<> into a typedef, otherwise registering will not work (bug? in Qt from the stoneage). Also do not use references to your typedef, will not work either.

Header

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
} mystruct;

typedef QVector<mystruct> myvector;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(myvector);
```

Source

```
void MainWindow::test()
{
    qRegisterMetaType<myvector>();

    connect(this, SIGNAL(sigRec(myvector)), SLOT(slotRec(myvector)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    mystruct x = {1,2};
    myvector v;
    v.append(x);
    emit sigRec(v);
}

void MainWindow::slotRec(myvector s)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out things to be taken care. This save me lot of time and energy. Also u have used QVector; for std::vector, what changes need to be done? should vector also be registered separately in that case. Also in the qregisterMetaType in the parentheses anything else required?, Today for string, it didnt work if kept empty. Only this worked qRegister..<std::string>("string"). Also do i need to be careful about namespace std?

Comment: Regarding queued connection, i understand as it directly decides queued connection if 2 threads are involved between signals and slots, as default is auto. the error i got also is "string not defined for different thread .. ". Hope i am not misunderstanding that concept.

Comment: Also keep in mind that there is a new recommended connect syntax. See https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: I wanted to keep in style with the question - if there is an existing project, you would not want to change style unless you change all places where connect is called. But you are right in case of a new project!

Comment: The 4-argument versions are equivalent to passing `Qt::AutoConnection`, **not** `Qt::DirectConnection`, so whether you get a queued or direct connection will depend on whether the sender and receiver belong to the same thread or not.

Comment: I prefer the excplicit fifth parameter, even though I must admit, I have never thought about AutoConnection. Might make code more portable but I I think I prefer the explicit QuededConnection to indicate the thread decoupling to the reader of my sources.

Comment: Regarding `std::vector`: Simply replace the definition of myvector by `typedef std::vector<mystruct> myvector;` and replace `append` by `push_back` in `test()`. Nothing else should change.

Comment: it worked. Note:  qRegisterMetaType<myvector>("myvector") needed that "myvector" in my case. Thanks Jens and others as well.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo
Done!